# bitxor on c++ strings

Tags: c++, string, matlab, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to port the matlab-function `bitxor` to c++ to achieve a bitwise XOR-operation on std::strings.

Now I'm not sure whether this actually works in general? If I take the strings and perform XOR on the individual characters, I observe the following:

- `c=xor(a, b); d=xor(a, c)` works fine, i.e. `d` equals `b`.
- "3" is bitwise `00110011` whereas `int a=3` is bitwise `00000011`. Thus, "3" xor "2" returns a character that can't be displayed but which equals 1.

Does anyone know whether - and if yes how - it is possible to perform this bitwise XOR on strings? It is used for network coding stuff.

Comment: Do you want to xor each character in the string?

Comment: Do the strings always just contain digits? DO you need to change them to integers first?

Comment: Characters of digits aren't the equivalent of their numerical values. Have a look how ASCII characters are encoded!

Comment: Don't use `std::string` to hold numeric values.  Use `std::vector<int>` or something similar.

Comment: Also depending on what exactly you try to achieve maybe std::bitset can be handy for your usecase.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure it works the same way in MATLAB -- xoring two ASCII digits will give you a result that isn't an ASCII digit.

Comment: doctorlove & Ivaylo: I'll have to XOR data packets which were serialized by the [boost framework](http://www.boost.org). This serialized string contains a signature which consists of letters and the binary data afterwards... Ben: Which container would you suggest for binary data of variable length?

Comment: Why are the packets strings? Shouldn't they be arrays of bytes?

Comment: @harold I guess a string isn't anything else than an array of chars which means it's an array of bytes - isn't it?

Comment: Sort of, I guess. But it's more than a little misleading, and I wouldn't count on everything working right in the face of invalid characters (especially `\0`, which you can have in a C++ string, but gives trouble *at least* when converting to/from cstrings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to xor each character in the string, just iterate through the string and create new one:

```
std::string bitxor(std::string x, std::string y)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    // works properly only if they have same length!
   for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
   {

       ss <<  (x.at(i) ^ y.at(i));
   }


    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "123";
    std::string b = "324";
    std::string c = bitxor(a, b);
    std::string d = bitxor(c, b);

    std::cout << a << "==" << d << std::endl; // Prints 123 == 123

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nemajna! However, this doesn't hold for `c=bitxor(a,b); d=bitxor(c,b); a==d`, does it?

Comment: of course you're right, thanks! Just one more question: Why do you substract '0'? Wouldn't it return the same result if you just wrote `ss << (x.at(i) ^ y.at(i));` (since you substract the same bits from both values) - or what's the reason behind this substraction?